# Servlet Performance: Generate Static Content Dynamically?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, static-content

I have a web-page with content, which has to be generated. However, the generation could happen up-front, it's basically not more than generating multiple versions of the same file. I.e. I have a template, which has to be filled with different property files.

Regarding performance, is it worth to pre-generate the files? Or should I run a servlet or JSP page and fill the template dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend entirely on what your performance requirements are. For a typical webapp, put it in a JSP, and don't worry about it. Otherwise, do some profiling to determine exactly what your needs are for performance improvements.